# Regular expression that matches a pattern but excludes a match when it starts with a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of the format:

> PATTERN or abcPATTERNdef or PATTERN or <<[TEST].[PATTERN]>>

I have created a regular expression (in JavaScript) as `(^PATTERN)|([^\[]PATTERN)` which *is* returning the first 3 occurrences while ignoring the last one, however I also seem to be getting the preceding character in the returned matches:

"PATTERN", "cPATTERN" and " PATTERN"

What I need are the matches without the preceding character.

I'm new to regular expressions and apologize if the question reflects that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have good support for lookbehinds, but if your format is going to remain the same, you can try something like this:

```
PATTERN(?!])
```

It matches all occurrences of "PATTERN" that are not followed by a `]`.

Let me know if this isn't the case, and I will update my answer to include the check for the opening `[`.

Comment: I was just reading negative lookahead (or lookbehind), and seems I stumbled onto a similar expression.

This one works for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do.  Can you see if this works?

```
(^PATTERN)|[^\[](PATTERN)
```

Are you trying to find all the strings between the PATTERN's?

Comment: It will still match one character before.

Comment: Can't you just look for (PATTERN) ?  That will give you all the matches for PATTERN

Comment: He wants to ignore the last one in the example.

Comment: @Adam - My requirement is to find all the matches of a word ('PATTERN') in a string *except* when the word is contained inside square-brackets. So I started out by creating an expression that ignores any match of the word that has a starting square bracket.